# Split legend into two lines

Tags: r, legend

I have been trying to split my legend into two lines but have not been successful (or another attempt is to add a new legend).
My line of code for the legend is simply like this:

```
legend("top",c("P1","P2", "P3", "P4","P5","P6"),lty=c(1,3,3,1,3,3),lwd=2,bty="n", col=c("deepskyblue2","deepskyblue2","red","deepskyblue2","deepskyblue2","red"))
```

I want to have P1, P2, P3 on the same line then P4,P5,P6 on the 2nd line right under. 
Please can somebody give me some help.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `ncol` option in `legend` to have 3 columns (and 2 rows). You also have to index them to get the order rowwise.

```
plot(1:10)
legend_order <- matrix(1:6,ncol=3,byrow = TRUE)
legend("top",c("P1","P2", "P3", "P4","P5","P6")[legend_order],
       lty=c(1,3,3,1,3,3)[legend_order],
       lwd=2,bty="n", 
       col=c("deepskyblue2","deepskyblue2","red",
             "deepskyblue2","deepskyblue2","red")[legend_order],
       ncol=3)
```

[image]